# Expire headers htacces for phpThumb

Tags: .htaccess, web

How to define expire headers in .htacces for images generated like this one:

```
 phpThumb.php?src=/images/galleries/9e8959676e5a8e8937a2843f8d9989899d09bcee-----d8d738542c04367bf90d32f04e1cbceedb896a65-----.jpg&w=400&h=200&far=1&zc=1&q=99&sia=custom-filename
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify a cache validator for images created by imagejpeg/imagepng functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158768/specify-a-cache-validator-for-images-created-by-imagejpeg-imagepng-functions)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution for me is here: 
https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/phpThumb/pull/50/files